# How to set multiple items as selected in ListBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, selected, listitem

I have one **ListBox** with selection mode of multiple. In code behind, I want to set some values as selected. These values are present in a **ListItems[]** named **'Names'**.

HTML code:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbto" class="chosen" runat="server" Width="450px" 
 Height="20px" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem>Mandy</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Amit</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>sundar</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ragu</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>raju</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

**ListItem[] Names** contains **'ragu'** and **'raju'**. Now, when the page loads, the **ListBox** should contain **'ragu'** and **'raju'** as selected values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about setting the [`Selected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.selected.aspx)-property of the [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx)?

```
var names = new List<string>(new string[] { "ragu", "raju" });

foreach (var item in lbto.Items)
{
    if (names.Contains(item.Text))
        item.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: You can set more than one item to `Selected` with the method described above. Updated the answer.

Comment: If `lbto` contain 100 items means, it will check whole 100 items. will it take more time?

Comment: `foreach` means, that it will check each item, or what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FindByValue` method

```
foreach (string item in stringList)
    lbxList.Items.FindByValue(item).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] IndexList = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
for (int i = 0; i < IndexList.Length; i++)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > IndexList[i])
    {
        listBoxFX.SetSelected(IndexList[i], true);
    }
}
```

Comment: New answers to old, well-answered questions require ample explanation as to how they complement the other answers.

Comment: I agree, but gave +1 just for stating the `SetSelected` method, which turned out to be what I was looking for. Other answers seem no longer to apply to a list box which contains objects so I can't set `Selected` on them.

Answer (score -1):

Using One line of linq

```
lbto.Items.Cast<String>().ForEach(i => i.Selected = names.Contains(i.Text));
```

OR

```
lbto.Items.OfType<string>().ForEach(i => i.Selected = names.Contains(i.Text));
```

Comment: I get an error saying that ListItemCollection does not have a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach'

Comment: The solution does not work. 
   
 
I get an error saying that ListItemCollection does not have a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach'

Comment: System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<string> does not contains a definition for Foreach.
I used a foreach statement instead.

Comment: @rhose87 you need to have using directive for System.Linq