# How to set multiple selected values for listbox

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

selectedCityGuidI am not able to set selected values for a multi select listbox.
My above code always sets the last value (ie.paris) as the selected value.
But I need to set multiple selected values for the listbox.
Below is my code.

```
<select size="4" name="lstcity" multiple="multiple" id="lstcity" style="height:100px;">
    <option value="40faf89d-4b22-4954-96f1-86b17720e7a6">Newyork</option>
    <option value="994a3301-a9d3-4f11-9d0e-8eb040a6150e">London</option>
    <option value="7adb079a-3403-45d9-b166-f463d9cd6031">Shangai</option>
    <option value="748dfec6-b854-4395-8d98-5dc2399e658d">Dubai</option>
    <option value="ec3edc8c-f8ad-406a-9635-51585948872f">Paris</option>
    <option value="B3F3A7AC-F27C-4B9D-8625-CB03DA9286D9">Berlin</option>
</select>


var selectedCityGuid = "40faf89d-4b22-4954-96f1-86b17720e7a6|ec3edc8c-f8ad-406a-9635-51585948872f"; //newyork|paris

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedCityGuid))
{
    var cityGuids = selectedCityGuid.Split('|');
    foreach (string id in cityGuids)
    {
            lstcity.SelectedValue = id;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set multiple items are selected in ListBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943883/how-to-set-multiple-items-are-selected-in-listbox)

Comment: not correct,  above article shows how to set Text/name property not value. I tried but couldn't get to work it

Comment: Your code example sure looks like a mixture of HTML, JavaScript, and C#. Are you sure you've got that formatted correctly?

Comment: I only ask because if you *are* trying to use JavaScript, that's a very different matter than the C# that you tagged and that it resembles. If you're using C#, you should be using ASP.NET's `ListBox` control, not an HTML `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting SelectedValue probably will overwrite a previously SelectedValue.  Try

```
var cityGuids = selectedCityGuid.Split('|');
for (var i=0; i<listcity.options.length; i++) {
    if (cityGuids.Contains(listcity.options[i].value))
        listcity.options[i].selected = true;
}
```

Comment: for some reason VS not showing Text property for item(item.Text). Am I missing any reference in order item to show Text property? I included Linq dll , still no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I originally gave you some ASP.NET web controls psuedocode.  I've updated the answer to provide a javaScript code sample.